# iOS view similar to add/edit contact

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to create a view similar to add/edit contact in iOS and there are a few things that are happening, and I'm not sure how they are implemented. Any help in understanding is greatly appreciated.

1. For each section in contacts i.e. name, phone number, email, etc are these each their own tableview or are these sections within a larger tableview?
2. When clicking done when adding or editing a contact, the unused tableview cells disappear. Is this using `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` or is there a hide method I haven't found? If it is using that method, then when clicking the edit contact button, how does the view brings back these unused tableview cells?
3. When clicking on a cell in the tableview cell when editing a contact, you are able to change the text. Is this a textfield within a tableview cell or is it actually modifying the label of the tableview cell?

I am not looking for any specific code, as a fairly new programmer I am just trying to understand the strategies/best way to implement these features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I tried a lot different ways to implement that. the easiest one: Subclass UITableViewCell and overwrite `setFrame:`. note that this is easy to achieve for grouped tables, but hard for plain ones. in the datasource's `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` create an object of this custom cell for the first section. use another identifier for cells of that section, so that only the correct cells will be re-used.
2. yes, I assume that. The controller has some sort of definition how many cells has to be show in edit mode and how many are actually used with some sort of information. you can easily create a array of indexPaths that must be deleted.
3. I would do it in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` by fetching the cell via `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, hide the label and unhide or add a textfield and make this first responder.

---

code for 1.

*the cell*

```
@interface InsetCell : UITableViewCell
@property(nonatomic)CGFloat inset;
@end



@implementation InsetCell

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    CGFloat inset;
    if (_inset == 0) {
        inset = 70;  //default value
    } else {
        inset = _inset;
    }
    frame.origin.x += inset;        
    [super setFrame:frame];
}

-(void)setInset:(CGFloat)inset
{
    _inset = inset;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

@end
```

---

a project that uses similar code
[image: screenshot insetcell]

Comment: The best answer I could have hoped for. Thanks!